# Can I use certain client-side Javascript APIs server-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, browser, html5-audio

I'm looking at some APIs which are meant to be used in a web browser.  They require the inclusion of their .js code and then present you with an API that returns audio.  Restating this in a more general way, these APIs return some stream of bytes (audio in this case) which the browser plays.

Can APIs of this type be used in server-side Javascript frameworks, eg. Node, where I make the API call and capture the resulting binary data in some variable?  I'm not sure I know how to map the semantics of what's going on in the browser to a server-side solution.

Here's an arbitrary example http://responsivevoice.org/api/

You include their Javascript in your page and then call `sampleLibrary.speak("hello world");`.  This results in audio coming back to the browser which is played.

Comment: Where's the code to call the API? Questions should have code

Comment: @JuanMendes I updated the question.

Comment: You can use it if you find or write a library that replicates whatever browser supplied features the JS you are using depends on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally many JavaScript's created for the browser can be run, but you have to mock a lot of browser functionality.

I took a look at the library you were linking to. Beautified it, and made some changes to it to make it a node module. Then you have to mock `navigator.userAgent`, `window` and `document`.

For document the library is using `addEventListener`. After mocking those I'm getting `RV: Voice synthesis not supported`. The library is using [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) through [Window.speechSynthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/speechSynthesis). This is not possible to mock.

It does however have a fallback functionality, which is to insert `AUDIO` tags through `createElement`. You will then get urls for generated audio files. Then you might be able to download these and do what you wanted to do on your server.

Comment: You actually made a node module already??  Wow.  So if I am understanding you correctly, the native implementation does *not* use the HTML 5 audio tag, but rather Web Speech API and Window.speechSynthesis as you said.  Further, if I understand correctly, if the browser doesn't support  Web Speech or speechSynthesis, it will dynamically render an HTML 5 <audio> tag.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Robert: Yes. Using `createElement`, and then call `load` and then `play` on it.